# Python - CSV to multiple JSONs

Tags: python, json, csv

Good afternoon sirs

I already know how to convert a csv file to json, however I am now unable to get each csv line saved in a different json.

Example:

Row 1: Json1.json

Row 2: Json2.json

The name of each file would be the fieldName of each row

Could someone give me a light on this?

The code follows:

```
import csv  
import json  

# Open the CSV  
f = open( '/path/to/filename.csv', 'rU' )  
# Change each fieldname to the appropriate field name. I know, so     difficult.  
reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = (    "fieldname0","fieldname1","fieldname2","fieldname3" ))  
# Parse the CSV into JSON  
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )  
print "JSON parsed!"  
# Save the JSON  
f = open( '/path/to/parsed.json', 'w')  
f.write(out)  
print "JSON saved!"
```

Comment: `[ row for row in reader ]` is `list(reader)` (do not overcomplicate your code).

Answer (score 4):

make a new json for each row

```
for idx, row in enumerate(reader,1):
   fout = open('Json'+str(idx)+'.json','w')
   fout.write(json.dumps(row))
   fout.close()
```

Comment: please close your file explicitly or use a `with` block. and use `format` to generate filename. Otherwise nice.